# Unable to Pack File. How to re-pack it?

Tags: packed-data

Similar questions have been asked before, but not quite the same, and no suitable answer found.

I rendered a scene on one computer.  Some texture images were on a USB memory stick plugged into "G:" on that computer.  They didn't get packed with the .blend file unfortunately.

Now I'm rendering that .blend file on another PC.  I have the memory stick, with those images.  I just want to put those images into the .blend file, and save it all packed together.  So can render that .blend file on any PC.  If someone could explain how please, in simple noob steps, I'd be very grateful.

The .blend file is not reading those images on the USB stick, because on this PC the USB port is H: instead of G:
Maybe could trick it into being a G: somehow, but that's not really the aim.

[image: Unable to pack file]

Thanks

Edit:  I can go to the Material Node for the missing texture, click the folder icon, and re-locate the texture image, and can render the scene properly.  But still, when saving the .blend file, it will not pack that image into the .blend file, even with "Automatically pack into .blend" selected.  So rendering on another PC will run into same problem.

Comment: Well obviously before packing your texture must be accessible and in the original place they were saved in the Blender path, so Blender can find them and pack them. If they were on a USB stick you must plug that USB stick before being able to pack, also the drive msut be assigned the same G drive letter before proceeding.

Comment: When the texture is not in the original place, how to point to that texture wherever it is, to "grab" it and then pack into the .blend file?

Comment: Navigate within blender where that texture is used (? Material, Node editor Modifier, Texture Painting, VSE, etc) press the browse button with the folder icon and browse to the new location

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Did that, the image rendered ok.  Clicked External Data -> ticked "Automatically pack into .blend".  Saved the file.  Now when I remove the memory stick, it still cannot find those textures.  So how to really pack the textures in to the .blend file, and get them to stay there no matter what?

Comment: And now Blender is saying both the G: drive images AND the H: images are not found.

Comment: I wonder if Blender limits the file size that can be included?  e.g. a large video filesize might not be packed?  Try a much smaller substitute for one of them in the form of a test video of just 30 secs.  That would tell you either way.

Comment: Not using any videos.  Only .PNG files for textures.  Largest is 64mb.  .blend file is 483mb (have used .blend files twice that size)

Comment: One technique that might be quicker than manually reloading all of the items that have a different drive letter, is to change the drive letter on the computer. See [this page](http://www.howtogeek.com/96298/assign-a-static-drive-letter-to-a-usb-drive-in-windows-7/) for instructions on how to proceed. And if the temporary computer is not yours, before changing the drive letter, make a note of the old one, and when you are done, change the letter back, so the machine when you leave it is the same as when you started using it.

Comment: Thanks.  I did that.  It works, but is just a temporary fix.  I'd like it to pack all the files, so the next time there are no missing files.  Because maybe next time I don't have the memory stick these files are on.